# How can I use the compositor on the result of the sequencer?

Tags: compositing-nodes, video-sequence-editor

I recently ran a renderfarm on a file with some compositing setup, but I forgot to set the composite output back to the *Composite* node instead of the *Viewer* I was temporarily using. Since the node setup didn't require anything besides the image data (i.e., no Z-buffer, object IDs, etc.) I figured that I could just run the compositor on each frame individually. However, this proved to be somewhwat difficult.

It seems that the sequencer is run *after* the compositor (despite their non-exclusivity in the *Post Processing* panel), so my idea to use an image strip in the sequencer for all the images that I already rendered didn't work—the render just copied the images into a new directory.

The *Movie Clip* node doesn't seem to accept an image strip as input, either, so that was not an option.

What I ended up doing was sequencing the animation to a movie file, then piping that into the *Movie Clip* node in the compositor. However, this required extra time, extra storage, and it rendered the default scene every frame before compositing, only to ignore the result.

Is there a way to use Blender's compositor either directly on an image sequence, or in conjunction with the video sequencer?

Comment: See [Color correction in the compositor from the video editor](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/2105/12).

Comment: @iKlsR: yes; that would work for basic adjustments, but it's not nearly as powerful as the full compositor.

Comment: is that Add on deleted..
Found the idea really useful ..
Thx for any info...

Comment: Looks like it is, but this looks related: [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fiDlNm9iJs4&hd=1), [script](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?221567-Edit-strip-with-compositor&p=2616544&viewfull=1#post2616544).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://blender.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://blender.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To use the rendered image sequence as input in the compositor, use the **Image** node. Select *any* file within the image sequence as input. Change the node's type from *Single Image* to *Image Sequence*, then set the sequence's length and first frame.

[image: 1a]

Comment: Sometimes I use the Blender compositor for altering a set of images in the same way, like a batch image processor. It's a powerful tool!

Answer (score 2):

To import a movie clip, its the same thing, just change Image Sequence to Movie Clip, and open the Movie! This also works with compositing effects.

Answer (score 2):

I found it is also essential to deselect the sequencer in properties under post production before doing any image sequence compositing.