# How to use Node Editor for the Video Sequencer?

Tags: node-editor, compositing-nodes, video-sequence-editor

How can I use the VSE with the node editor? I've tested about two addons and one script, and nothing has worked out.

The best result was to use the [VSE Compositor Node proxy](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?338248-VSE-Compositor-Node-proxy), but it is only affecting the "Viewer Node" in the node editor. When I want to render an animation, 
it renders pure VSE sequence without compositing.

Can someone tell me about a good working addon like this for Blender 2.72 or at least try the script I mentioned themself on Blender 2.72 to see if it's working? (maybe I'm doing something wrong, and it's not about the new Blender version)

Comment: related:http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/10720/can-i-add-the-output-of-the-vse-as-input-to-the-node-diagram

Comment: Have you tried using the scene strip? Its found under Add->Scene

Comment: Yes, I tried, maybe I set up something wrong:
http://pbrd.co/1J6mDcL
As you see, the cube from 3d world is blurred, but not the video clip ; ((( Can you tried the script from link that I wrote in the main question? Is it working for you in B2.72?

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that you add the composited scene back to the sequencer or VSE, then check that the VSE scene has the render properties Post > Sequencer ticked.

Comment: is there an easy way to do this for, say, 10 clips at once? And what about the audio, do I hvae to manually add the Movie clpi every time, delete the video, and line up the audio section with the scene??!