# How would I composite my rendered animation

Tags: rendering, animation, compositing-nodes

I'm new to blender. I created an animation, and it saved in my folder as 140 pictures, for each frame. How do I take all of that and add it into the compositor to add some effects that I need?

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/3779/599

Answer (score 2):

In the node editor, delete the "Render Layers" node and replace it with an "Image" node. Then click "Open" and navigate to folder where your animation images are saved. Hit <kbd>A</kbd> to select all the images, and then finally select "Open Images".

Answer (score -1):

I would rerender the animation into an avi file. Not a png file or something. You do this at the render tab under output. Just set it to a video type file. Your rendered animation will be a video already. Not separate images. And if you set up your compositing setup first, that setup will be applied to every frame of the animation.