# How to use video's edited in the video sequence editor in the compositor

Tags: compositing-nodes, video-sequence-editor

How do you use video's edited in the video sequence editor (VSE) in the compositor? Like is there a file-in node to input the output of the video editor into the compositor directly through the program, without rendering out to hard disk first?

thx,

-ty

Comment: Does [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/3782/42221) answer your question?

Comment: I think that's if the sequence is rendered all the way though.  I want to just edit in VSE and without rendering it out, use that edited footage in the compositor to like color correct etc.

Comment: Or do you HAVE to render out the video sequencer output to a file then bring it into the compositor with the image node

Comment: Yes I guess you need to render and then import in the Compositor as a video or as a series of images. Don't forget to disable the Output > Post Processing > Sequencer

Comment: How to roundtrip a VSE video clip in the compositor: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8-IQ2liVBpw

Comment: i just want to use the vse edited video in the compositor, not bring the composit result into the video editor