# How to get a MovieClipSequence Clip File via Python

Tags: python, scripting, video-sequence-editor

I was wondering whether it was possible to get the name of the Clip File of a Sequence via Python.

The current Sequence can be accessed via:

```
bpy.context.scene.sequence_editor.active_strip
```

I had a look at the Blender [Python API](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_76_2/bpy.types.MovieClipSequence.html), but did not find anything there.

**EDIT:**
I guess I did not express myself quite clearly. My question is whether (and if so - how) it would be posssible to get the associated *Movie Clip* of a VSE Strip of the type 'Clip' (imported via the *Movie Clip Editor* and then added to the VSE via *Add* -> *Clip...* -> *<Clipname>*).

Comment: I presume you mean something other than `...sequence_editor.active_strip.name`?

Comment: Yes, because that just returns the sequence's name, not the clip's one.

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean by reimporting...

Comment: I guess he means adding it as a fresh strip into the Sequencer again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually it doesn't seem possible.

When you open the Add menu (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>) you will see a list of all currently loaded Clips that have been opened in a `Movie Clip Editor` respectively their current Name properties.

Once you Add a "Clip" to the Sequencer it will initially get the original MovieClips name. But the corresponding MovieClip from the Strip of the Type MovieClipSequence being titled Clip in the Strips properties is only internally referenced. You cannot access it from the Sequencer anymore nor through the Python API. You can proof this via an Outliner view which is set to `Datablocks` Display Mode. There you can see all your `Movie Clips` in your **Blendfile Data**. Those have a name Property which can be set through Python via `bpy.data.movieclips["clip_name"].name`. Not that the Movie Clip is of the RNA Type `MovieClip`.

But when you look at your `Scenes`, `<scene_name>`, `Sequence Editor`, `Sequence Editor`, `All sequences` you can see all of your added Strips including the added Movie Clip (with it's original name) and an own name property which can be edited via `bpy.data.scenes['Scene'].sequence_editor.sequences_all["clip_name"].name`. Note its RNA Type `MovieClipSequence`.

When you now change the name of the MovieClip in the Sequencer you change the name of the MovieClipSequence object which can differ from the name of your MovieClip object. And only when they match the Strip in the sequencer will only show one name followed by a `|` and the MovieClipSequencer objects frame length. But as soon as you change one of these names, both will be displayed, the MovieClipSequenc objects first, followed by a colon `:` and the MovieClip objects name (followed by the `|` and the MovieClipSequence objects frame length). Unselected it's all a bit hard to read as imported Clips get a dark blue strip color by default.

But as soon as you see a colon `:` in a Clip strips name in the sequencer you can no longer match a MovieClip and a MovieClipSequencer as you cannot get the other ones name from one of these objects in Python as you can see there is no such link neither in the Python autocompletion nor in the Outliners Datablocks display mode. It's all handled internally by Blender for now.

Comment: Thank you! That is exactly what I wanted to know (although I find it very sad that it currently is that way).

Comment: Yeah... - but I'm happy I found something out about the Clips and how they work. Didn't use them yet in my projects. It's great to be able to insert them directly into the VSE using the undistortion feature and other advantages normal Movie Strips don't have. Anyways, feel free to open a [Feature Request](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Doc/Contact#Requesting_Features)...

Answer (score 4):

The active 'clip name' is the only *real reference* at the moment so avoid 'renaming' in *VSE*:

```
import bpy

seq = bpy.data.scenes['Scene'].sequence_editor
strip_name = seq.active_strip.name

print (bpy.data.movieclips[strip_name].filepath)
```

Console output: `/home/user/videos/file_name.mp4`

---

Otherwise (although not ideal) you could iterate through `bpy.data.movieclips` and compare the duration of the 'active strip' with 'all other' clips:

```
import bpy

seq = bpy.data.scenes['Scene'].sequence_editor
strip = seq.active_strip
strip_duration = strip.frame_duration

for i in bpy.data.movieclips:
    if (i.frame_duration == strip_duration):
        print (i.filepath)
```

Comment: This goes in the right direction, but when renaming the strip in vse this method - sadly - no longer applies.

Comment: Jep I know, but it seems that this is your only chance to get the clip directly, since there is no unique id at the moment.

Comment: Yeah... There seems to be one (because in vse the strip is named like that: "<name>: <clipname>"). It was sort of my question whether it is accessible it via Python :).

Comment: @PaulBrachmann As you can see it is accessible, but with limitations (at the moment). I've also tried comparing the clip pointers and thought about other solutions but unfortunately without any real success. Just out of interest: What you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm working on an AddOn that "precomposes" vse clips into scenes editeable via the compositor (in order to establish a NUKE like VFX/Compositing workflow in Blender). Therefore I have to know what the corresponding MovieClip to a MovieClipSequence is (to later on import it into the node editor).

Comment: I am including an EDL Importer for Sony Vegas (support of other applications is planned). But I want to give users the freedom to import clips on their own. (Also: As far as I know that solution would only work if the user never closed Blender in between.)

Comment: Nope you could also store it in a (blend) file...

Answer (score 0):

**This Answer was given before OPs edit while the question was still very vague, see my other answer as well.**

Just Run this Script in a Text Editor:

```
import bpy
for seq in bpy.data.scenes['Scene'].sequence_editor.sequences_all:
    print(seq.name)
```

You should then see the desired output in the `System Console` (Toggle via `Window` menu).

When you hover over a Strips name property, you get the Python hint: `MovieClipSequence.name` and its Python path below: `bpy.data.scenes['Scene'].sequence_editor.sequences_all["clip_name"].name`.

You can import your MovieClips in an Editor/View of the type `MovieClipEditor` where there is the MovieClip selection in its menu bar. When you hover over an imported and selected clip in this Dropdown Box you will see the Python hint: `MovieClip.name` with its the Python path below: `bpy.data.movieclips["clip_name"].name` - there are more Python properties on the MovieClip directly accessible like its complete `filepath`, the count of its `users`, its dimensions as a `size`-array (*with `[0]` being width and `[1]` being height*) or its `source` type (movie, image, ...) and more.

Comment: "AttributeError: 'MovieClipSequence' pbject has not attribute 'elements'"

Besides: Are you sure that is the right way of getting a Movie Clip's name (because if so, wouldn't  bpy.context.scene.sequence_editor.active_strip.filename do the job as well)?

Comment: no, not each strip has a filename. Even a MovieClipSequence doesn't have one... You can just get the name, I edited the answer.

Comment: There is no need to iterate through the sequences since you can use `active_strip`. To provide a different answer than mine (both looking more and more the same) you could check if the `select` attribute is true or false.

Comment: @poor: Yeah, one can use active_strip, but then the script is dependant on a selection. By iterating it isn't, you will get all the names from all the clips.

Comment: Who was downvoting this answer and why? Please leave a comment if somebody downvotes.