# Simple movie clip sharpening using Compositing - How to do this?

Tags: compositing-nodes, video, movie-clip-editor

I'm a novice in using Blender and am looking for an easy way to sharpen movie clips.  I believe I have to use Compositing, but am not being able to find some simple step-by-step methods to achieve this simple goal.  I looked at various tutorials on Youtube, but they are for more advanced users and use images (not movies) as examples.  How does one do this?  I have never done Compositing before.

I could not even load a single movie clip in my compositing window in the 'render layers' node that I had created in my movie project, which I believe is the first step.  If I could use just one filter successfully using the 'add filter...filter...sharpen', and apply it to my movie project, I would consider that to be a success.

I'm probably overlooking a simple step that most users are familiar with already.

I am using the latest 2.90.1 version installed on my Windows 10 laptop. I was able to create and render a short movie by joining several short movie clips shot on my DSLR camera using Blender.  Although, I am pretty sure my camera technique and equipment used was good, the final rendered movie in 24 fps, at 1920x1080 resolution is not sharp.  The built in camera picture profile I used was 'flat' with no sharpening.  I know I nailed the exposure and focus, used a tripod, a professional quality lens, etc...

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Add an *Input* > *Image* node (or Input Movie Clip node) and set the video file there.

Add a *Filter* > *Filter* node and set it to sharpen mode.

Plug the output image to the composite input and render.

[image]

Comment: I was able to do what you suggested but only for a new VFX project.  How do I apply sharpening to a movie I made using a 'File...New...Video Editing' project?  I want to be able to apply sharpening to each movie clip in that project. Thank you

Comment: I think this will work:  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2105/color-correction-in-the-compositor-from-the-video-editor